# How to avoid race condition when acquiring a mutex?

Tags: c#, .net, mutex, race-condition

I am using a named system mutex to synchronise 2 processes.  This is how I am currently acquiring a mutex within my application:

```
using System.Threading;

public static bool AcquireMutex()
{
    // Protect against double acquisitions
    if (MyMutex != null)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Failed to acquire mutex");
    }

    try
    {
        // See if a named system mutex has already been created - if it has,
        // wait a short amount of time for its release.
        MyMutex = Mutex.OpenExisting(MutexName);
        if (!MyMutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), false))
        {
            // MyMutex still being held
            MyMutex = null;
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        // MyMutex doesn't exist so create it
        MyMutex = new Mutex(true, MutexName);
    }

    return true;
}
```

`OpenExisting` will throw an exception if the named system mutex with `MutexName` doesn't exist, allowing my application to create it.

However, there seems to be a race condition here - if `OpenExisting` throws, there is a small window before the call to `new Mutex` where the other application may have acquired the mutex.

What is the best way to avoid this race condition and make this code more reliable?

A colleague mentioned that he was using `CreateMutex` from the Win32 Platform SDK in his code (the other process which needs to be synchronised).  This doesn't seem to be natively supported by the .NET Framework, however.  So I'm not sure it's the best solution for my code.

---

**Update**

Based on the answer from @David Schwartz, here is my new code:

```
public static bool AcquireMutex()
{
    // Protect against double acquisitions
    if (MyMutex != null)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Failed to acquire mutex");
    }

    bool createdNew;
    MyMutex = new Mutex(true, MutexName, out createdNew);
    if (createdNew)
    {
        // Mutex was created so ownership is guaranteed; no need to wait on it.
        return true;
    }

    try
    {
        if (!MyMutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), false))
        {
            MyMutex = null;
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (AbandonedMutexException)
    {
        // Other application was aborted, which led to an abandoned mutex.
        // This is fine, as we have still successfully acquired the mutex.
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this cannot work.  You need to make one of the processes the boss, the one that creates it.  Pick one, usually the first one.  If the other process cannot open it then there's something really wrong.  It needs to wait.

Comment: @Hans - I have made changes based on David Schwartz's answer - can you please see my updated code, and let me know if it looks correct.

Comment: AbandonedMutexException is only thrown if you are doing something seriously wrong. I would not silence it like in the code above but let my global exception handler log it for further analysis. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.abandonedmutexexception(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a constructor specifically designed for this purpose. From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwe34f1k.aspx#Y0):

> **createdNew**
>       Type: *System.Boolean*
>   When this method returns, contains a Boolean that is true if a local mutex was created (that is, if name is null or an empty string) or if the specified named system mutex was created; false if the specified named system mutex already existed. This parameter is passed uninitialized.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - can you please see my updated code in the original question, and let me know if it looks correct.